# Start and embed external process in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, process, window, external

I'm attempting to start a non-WPF process with XAML, and assign the window of the external application as my main window. Is this possible? The intent is to utilize some of XAML's convenient event handlers without digging into hooks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you question is : "can I use XAML alone to listen to events from external app/different process" - than answer is **no** - there is no built in way to listen to events from other processes in a first place.

If the question: "can I use XAML syntax to configure my own code that subscribes to events from external applications" - than answer is yes, but you'll not only need to implement code that wires up listening for remote events but also hook into XAML processing or maybe proxy events.

Comment: Yes, I would like to subscribe to touch events sent to the external application and configure my code that way.

Comment: @jbecar - you still need to write code that hooks external events - there is no support in .Net to listen for events in remote application. Than you can use XAML to configure you own code.